# xterm: circled numbers (U+2460-U+2470) only the left half of the glyph is displayed

Tags: linux, terminal, fonts, unicode, xterm

I am using the version of xterm that ships with ubuntu 21.04 (package xterm361-1ubuntu3) and some characters such as circled numbers are not displayed correctly: the right half of the character is clipped/truncated.

At the bash prompt:

```
$ echo $'\u2460\u2461\u2462' etc.
```

I only see the left half of the circle and part of the 1, 2, 3, etc. digit. The right half is overlaid by the following character (or the left half thereof in this case).

When I run the same command on gnome-terminal or KDE's Konsole (on the same system) I can see the whole characters/glyphs tightly packed & touching each other but quite readable.

I start xterm with the following flags:

```
$ xterm -name xterm -u8 +vb -tn "xterm-256color" -fa 'Inconsolata for Powerline' -fs 6 -maximize
```

I can see that quite a number of characters in the same range (parenthesized letters, old style B&W smileys, some stars, arrows... other pseudo graphics & symbols...) behave likewise.

I have tried other outline fonts (Inconsolata, DejaVuSansMono, Unifont...) with the same result.

Is this the expected behaviour or do I need to run xterm with a specific flag / X resource (or compile time configure option perhaps) so that these characters are correctly rendered?

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. These characters *are* wider, because they're loaded from a completely different font.

DejaVu Sans Mono actually **doesn't have** glyphs for circled numbers, as you can see by opening the font in an editor (such as FontForge). So when a program needs to show them, they're being loaded from a different font – possibly one with different metrics, and possibly one that isn't even monospace at all.

[image: Screenshot of DejaVuSansMono.ttf loaded in FontForge, showing a grid of glyphs around the "CIRCLED DIGIT" range, most of which is completely empty cells indicating "not present in this font" save for one or two.]

How the result is handled depends on each terminal's internal text rendering method. (Some terminals might draw each grid cell separately, others might try to draw each line as a single unit; some draw a solid background, others draw directly on top of the previous character.)

The primary font does influence the fallback fonts that are being used (to some extent, e.g. some monospace fonts aren't actually categorized correctly, and fontconfig ends up suggesting non-monospace fallbacks for them). There may also be differences between the text drawing libraries used by each terminal (Xterm uses the Xft interface to FreeType; gnome-terminal uses Pango; etc.)

Comment: Perhaps it's only a matter of wording but I do not consider it 'normal' that an application whose main function is to display text (in a shell... vim... mutt...etc.) should come up with garbled text. I would call this a bug. I did realize/guess there might be some kind of glyph substitution going on and checked the 'Inconsolata for Powerline' font (from the github pw collection) in fontforge and it does have the glyphs for circled numbers. In any case this answer does not really answer my question... So let me reword it as what's Joe User supposed to do about this state of affairs?